# Elasticsearch 7.10 wont accept keywords?

Tags: elasticsearch, curl

I have a fresh Elasticsearch 7.10 with the following mapping

```
  "log": {
    "mappings": {
      "properties": {
        "Subject": {
          "type": "text"
        },
        "code": {
          "type": "keyword"
        },
        "host_message": {
          "type": "text"
        },
        "hostname": {
          "type": "keyword"
        },
        "message_id": {
          "type": "keyword"
        },
        "remote": {
          "type": "keyword"
        },
        "sender": {
          "type": "keyword"
        },
        "server": {
          "type": "keyword"
        },
        "status": {
          "type": "keyword"
        },
        "ts": {
          "type": "date"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Now I simply want to index a document.

```
curl -k -uelastic:secret -H "Content-Type: application/json" -XPUT https://172.16.11.11:9200/log/info/B8DF712CEE -d ' {"ts": "1604790002000",
   "Subject": "random text",
   "message_id": "B8DF712CEE",
   "receiver": "root@localhost",
   "sender": "None",
   "code": "ok",
   "host_message": "(delivered to mailbox)",
   "hostname": "localhost",
   "dsn": "2.0.0",
   "status": "sent",
   "remote": ""}
'
```

That gives me a *illegal_argument_exception*

```
{"error":{"root_cause":[{"type":"illegal_argument_exception","reason":"mapper [remote] cannot be changed from type [keyword] to [text]"}],"type":"illegal_argument_exception","reason":"mapper [remote] cannot be changed from type [keyword] to [text]"},"status":400}
```

That worked in pretty much every version before.
I searched the Interwebs, but didnt find anything. I wasnt even aware there was a difference between *text* and *keyword* while PUTting.

I'll try to change my mapping to a multifield, but any info is greatly appreciated.

Comment: You need to replace `info` by `_doc` in your URL

Answer (score 0):

When you create index and put mappings in Elasticsearch 7.10 you don't state the "type" and it's automatically set as "_doc" in your index. So you need to change your url to

`https://172.16.11.11:9200/log/_doc/B8DF712CEE`

and I think u need to change to POST operation

hope that works.